# Install avisynth under Linux via SSH

Tags: wine, avisynth

I have a Linux server (Ubuntu OS) to which I have access via SSH and wish to install avisynth on it. I know Windows applications can be installed with the help of Wine, but the problem is how I manage to install the application (avisynth) thru SSH, that is, without a graphical interface? Can Wine be somehow configured to manage such a case? What should I do to install avisynth via SSH? (I am not interested in other applications.)

Answer (score 2):

With SSH, you can do X11 forwarding. It is easy with [PuTTY](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-x-forwarding). You'll need an X server on your station, such as [Xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/).